# Apache2 Not Starting

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

When I try to start Apache2 it fails then if I do

```
Apache2 -e Debug
```

It comes up with these errors

```
[Thu Feb 09 09:46:08.244772 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16287] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Feb 09 09:46:08.245358 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16287] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Feb 09 09:46:08.245695 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16287] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Feb 09 09:46:08.245764 2017] [core:warn] [pid 16287] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I have no idea what is wrong with the server as it used to work but then it stopped working after trying to install OpenLDAP.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 and apache 2.4.18

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling apache but that does not work.

Comment: Well...what *is* line 74 in apache2.conf?

Comment: In order to get help, you need at least to post the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`!

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to add, This is whats on line 74
'Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default'

Comment: @HarryCameron What's in your `/etc/apache2/envvars` file?

Comment: What are you looking for precisely?

Comment: @HarryCameron [Apache2 environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html). `APACHE_LOCK_DIR`, `APACHE_LOG_DIR`, `APACHE_RUN_DIR`, and so on...

Comment: @Lenniey This is what I get
`export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX¬`

Comment: @HarryCameron Please show us the complete config-files, `/etc/apache2/envvars` and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but without the comments. (And just for "fun", try to disable all your sites and start apache again)

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my envvars file http://prntscr.com/e6gt76

Comment: @HarryCameron and your apache2.conf? Also did you try my last suggestion?

Comment: Here are the screenshots of my apache2.conf http://prntscr.com/e6iwso http://prntscr.com/e6iydc http://prntscr.com/e6iyog and http://prntscr.com/e6iyyz How would I go about disabling my site?

Answer (score 1):

This variable may be set by init script - for example /etc/init.d/apache or /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.
Try starting it with init script.

Moreover, please write more about OS (which version) and Apache install (custom build or repository?).

Comment: It comes back ok but if I run
    service --status-all apache comes back as off

Comment: @HarryCameron this answer should do the trick. Starting apache2 using the binary *usually* won't work. Start it via `sudo service apache2 start|stop|restart`

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have tried all of the service apache2 options

Comment: I do not undestarnd - so it start without errors (via init script) but shut down immediately?
If yes, post adequate error.log entries and check it via command:
systemctl status httpd.service

Comment: The error.log file is empty